# update Matlibpro in real time in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, wxpython

Good morning/evening,

Currently I am writing a program that communicates with a serial device to receive voltage and current measurements. I have the data output to their own text boxes in wxPython, and I have a timer set up so that it constantly polls the device as long as the program is open. I wanted to take it a step further, so I decided to add a graph to the GUI as well.

So far, here is what I have:

```
class Slot1DetailFrame(wx.Frame):

      def __init__(self):
           """Constructor"""
           wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Slot 1 Specifications")
           self.initialize()

           self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
           self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.update, self.timer)
           self.timer.Start(2000)

      def initialize(self):

       sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap = 5, vgap = 5)

       """ LABELS """
       self.VoltageLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Voltage', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
       sizer.Add(self.VoltageLabel, (0,1))
       self.CurrentLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Current', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
       sizer.Add(self.CurrentLabel, (0,2))
       self.PowerLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Power', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
       sizer.Add(self.PowerLabel, (0,3))
       self.TotalPowerLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Total Power', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
       sizer.Add(self.TotalPowerLabel, (4,2))


       """ RAIL 1 """
       self.Rail1Label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Rail 1:', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail1Label, (1,0))

       self.Rail1Voltage = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail1Voltage, (1,1),(1,1))

       self.Rail1Current = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail1Current, (1,2),(1,1))

       self.Rail1Power = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail1Power, (1, 3),(1,1))

       self.Rail1Config = wx.Button(self, -1,  "Configure")
       sizer.Add(self.Rail1Config,(1, 4), (1, 1))

       """ RAIL 2 """
       self.Rail2Label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Rail 2:', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail2Label, (2,0))

       self.Rail2Voltage = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail2Voltage, (2,1),(1,1))

       self.Rail2Current = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail2Current, (2,2),(1,1))

       self.Rail2Power = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail2Power, (2, 3),(1,1))

       self.Rail2Config = wx.Button(self, -1,  "Configure")
       sizer.Add(self.Rail2Config,(2, 4), (1, 1))

       """ RAIL 3 """
       self.Rail3Label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Rail 3:', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail3Label, (3,0))

       self.Rail3Voltage = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail3Voltage, (3,1),(1,1))       

       self.Rail3Current = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail3Current, (3,2),(1,1))

       self.Rail3Power = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_READONLY)
       sizer.Add(self.Rail3Power, (3,3),(1,1))   

       self.Rail3Config = wx.Button(self, -1,  "Configure")
       sizer.Add(self.Rail3Config,(3, 4), (1, 1))

       """ TOTAL POWER """
       self.TotalPower = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize)
       sizer.Add(self.TotalPower, (4,3))

       """ TEMPERATURE GRAPH """
       x = 0
       y = 0
       self.fig = Figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=100)
       self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
       self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
       self.ax.set_xlim(0,100)
       self.ax.set_ylim(0,100)
       line,= self.ax.plot(x,y,'-')

       # Add figure
       sizer.Add(self.canvas, (5,0), (5,5), wx.EXPAND)

       self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
       sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
       sizer.AddGrowableCol(1)

      def update(self, event):

       ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=5, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False, interCharTimeout=None)

       """ VOLTAGE """
       ser.flushInput()
       ser.flushOutput()
       ser.write('3/1/')
       time.sleep(.1)
       Rail1Volt = ser.readline()
       self.Rail1Voltage.SetValue(Rail1Volt[0:6] + "V")
       Rail2Volt = ser.readline()
       self.Rail2Voltage.SetValue(Rail2Volt[0:6] + "V")
       Rail3Volt = ser.readline()
       self.Rail3Voltage.SetValue(Rail3Volt[0:6] + "V")

       """ CURRENT """
       ser.flushInput()
       ser.flushOutput()
       ser.write('3/2/')
       time.sleep(.1)
       Rail1Cur = ser.readline()
       self.Rail1Current.SetValue(Rail1Cur[0:6] + "A")
       Rail2Cur = ser.readline()
       self.Rail2Current.SetValue(Rail2Cur[0:6] + "A")
       Rail3Cur = ser.readline()
       self.Rail3Current.SetValue(Rail3Cur[0:6] + "A")

       """ POWER """
       Rail1Pow = float(Rail1Cur) * float(Rail1Volt)
       self.Rail1Power.SetValue((str(Rail1Pow))[0:6] + "W")
       Rail2Pow = float(Rail2Cur) * float(Rail2Volt)
       self.Rail2Power.SetValue((str(Rail2Pow))[0:6] + "W") 
       Rail3Pow = float(Rail3Cur) * float(Rail3Volt)
       self.Rail3Power.SetValue((str(Rail3Pow))[0:6] + "W")

       TotalPow = Rail1Pow + Rail2Pow + Rail3Pow
       self.TotalPower.SetValue(str(TotalPow) + "W")
```

Which creates a GUI such as this:

[image]

Now, the problem I am facing is getting the graph to update the values in real time as well. For simplicity, I have not tried to add the voltage, current, and power readings to the graph, but just execute a loop to plot a line. This was the code that I based my program on:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np

x=0
y=0 

fig=plt.figure(1)
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,1000)
line,=ax.plot(x,y,'-')

for i in range(0,1000):
    x = np.concatenate((line.get_xdata(),[i]))
    y = np.concatenate((line.get_ydata(),[i]))
    line.set_data(x,y)
    plt.pause(.1)
    if i > 100:
        ax.set_xlim(i-100, 100+i)
```

The problem is that I do not know where to put this code/implement it to get it to work properly. If I put it in def initialize with the rest of the initialized graph, it executes, but causes the program to wait until it plots all the points to open up. Also, I don't see how this will help me since I would like to just put it in the update function and have it update when the voltage/current/power measurements update. But, when I put it in this def, it loads the program automatically but does not print any data to the graph.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.